# Get rows for columns with null details

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have two tables assignment and extra_assignment_Details. I have to extract the assignment details of those employees with the category as "performance". 
I have ccreated a query for this , but it is only getting the detail of those employees who value is entered in this category column. I also want those whose value is not there in this column. Currently I am using the below query :

```
SELECT DISTINCT PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER "Assignment Number", 
to_char(to_date(PAEI.AEI_INFORMATION_DATE1),'DD-MON-YYYY') "Effective Date",
 PAEI.AEI_ATTRIBUTE2 Site,
PAEI.AEI_ATTRIBUTE4 "Performance Review Eligibility"    
FROM 
PER_ASSIGNMENT_EXTRA_INFO_M PAEI,
PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M PAAM
WHERE PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_ID= PAEI.ASSIGNMENT_ID
and paam.assignment_type ='E'
and paeiINFORMATION_TYPE(+) ='Performance'
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) between PAAM.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PAAM.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) between PAEI.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PAEI.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
```

even if the values are not eneterd in information_type performance we should get an output

Answer (score 0):

You want a `LEFT JOIN` and you should learn to write it as such:

```
SELECT PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER as "Assignment Number", 
       to_char(to_date(PAEI.AEI_INFORMATION_DATE1),'DD-MON-YYYY') as "Effective Date",
       PAEI.AEI_ATTRIBUTE2 as Site,
       PAEI.AEI_ATTRIBUTE4 as "Performance Review Eligibility"    
FROM PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M PAAM LEFT JOIN
     PER_ASSIGNMENT_EXTRA_INFO_M PAEI
     ON PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_ID = PAEI.ASSIGNMENT_ID AND
        paei.INFORMATION_TYPE = 'Performance' AND
        TRUNC(SYSDATE) between PAEI.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PAEI.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
WHERE paam.assignment_type ='E' AND
      TRUNC(SYSDATE) between PAAM.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PAAM.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
```